# How to get population size instead of person-years when using stsplit and strate in Stata?

Tags: stata, frequency, survival-analysis

**How to get number of people in the group instead of person-years when using strate in Stata?**

Using cohort data, I have created a survival dataset in Stata like so:

```
stset end, id(person) failure(event==1) scale(365.25) enter(time start) origin(time dob)
            
stsplit ageband, at(0 (1) 5) after(time=dob) 
stsplit year, after(time=mdy(1,1,1960)) at(40 (1) 45) 
replace year = 1960 + year
            
strate ageband year sex, per(100000) output("rates.dta", replace)
```

where each `person` is born on `dob` and enters the study at `start` date and leaves at `end` date. If a `person` has an `event` (`event == 1`) during this period, then they leave at the event date.

`stset` creates the survival data.
`stsplit` splits the dataset into agebands (0-5 years old) and calendar year (2000-2005).

`strate` calculates the rates by each distinct value of `ageband` `year` `sex` and stores the summary data in "rates.dta". These summary results show, for each combination of `ageband` `year` `sex`: `_D` for number of events and `_Y` for person-years, which will be the numerator and denominator, respectively, when calculating rates.

I want to calculate the proportion of events `_D` out of the total number of people in each group.

Is there a way for `_Y` to be the total number of people within that group, e.g. ageband = 0, year = 2000, sex = 1 ?

How else can I get the number of people per group?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
* ADD before stset to get total number of people in the dataset
egen tag = tag(person)
egen N_total = total(tag)
drop tag

stset end, id(person) failure(event==1) scale(365.25) enter(time start) origin(time dob)
            
stsplit ageband, at(0 (1) 5) after(time=dob) 
stsplit year, after(time=mdy(1,1,1960)) at(40 (1) 45) 
replace year = 1960 + year

* ADD for each variable / group that you want to find the number of people in
egen tag = tag(person ageband)
egen N_ageband = total(tag), by(ageband)
drop tag

egen tag = tag(person year)
egen N_year = total(tag), by(year)
drop tag

egen tag = tag(person sex)
egen N_sex = total(tag), by(sex)
drop tag

* KEEP variables of interest
keep person event ageband year sex N_total N_ageband N_year N_sex

collapse (mean) N_total N_ageband N_year N_sex, by(ageband sex year person) 
            
* SAVE
save "proportions.dta", replace


strate ageband year sex, per(100000) output("rates.dta", replace)
```

Then later, for each group (total, ageband, year, sex) merge your `rates.dta` file with the `proportions.dta` file:

```
foreach var in total ageband year sex {
    use "rates.dta", clear
    merge m:1 person sex ageband year using "proportions.dta", keep(match) nogen
    if `var'==total collapse (sum) _D N_`var'
    else collapse (sum) _D N_`var', by(`var')

    * do any other processing with the results

    save "proportions_by_`var'.dta", replace
}
```